# Convert array of elements to json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have an array of pks with repeated pk value which I want to convert into a jSON object where

```
obj.id = pk
obj.count = count of pk in array
```

I tried using `JSON.stringify` library but `obj.id`  doesn't give me any pk.

Comment: What is a JSON object? `JSON.stringify` maybe?

Comment: what is a `pk`? Show more data and give better explanation of what you need

Comment: Are you sure you want JSON or just convert the array to an object structure? Please post an example of your data and the result you want, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: I am ok with convering it to an object structure. But I want count of each array entry.

Comment: I'm just checking wether you really want JSON and where exactly you are having problems with. And we still need examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library

And call:

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,3];
var unique = {};
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
  if (!unique.hasOwnProperty(x[i])) {
     unique[x[i]] = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    unique[x[i]]++;
  }
}
```

Produces `{1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}`

You can then do this to turn that into the object structure you want

```
var objArray = [];

for (var key in unique) {
  objArray.push({id: key, count: unique[key]});
}
```

Produces `[{id: 1, count: 3},{id: 2, count: 3},{id: 3, count: 2},{id: 4, count: 1}]`